# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR when deploying Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration

After typing `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I got an error looking like,

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "notified_bies" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "notifications" ("id" bigserial primary key, "user_id"     bigint, "notified_by_id" bigint, "post_id" bigint, "identifier" integer,     "notice_type" character varying, "read" boolean, "created_at" timestamp NOT     NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_b080fb4855"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_ff009aac1a"
FOREIGN KEY ("notified_by_id")
  REFERENCES "notified_bies" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_ff8a02c41d"
FOREIGN KEY ("post_id")
  REFERENCES "posts" ("id")
)
```

and, here this is the list of migrate files in db folder.

```
20180411215502_create_posts.rb
20180411215935_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb
20180411225346_devise_create_users.rb
20180411230346_add_user_name_to_users.rb
20180411232041_add_user_id_to_posts.rb
20180412001819_create_comments.rb
20180412164718_add_attachment_avatar_to_users.rb
20180412164800_add_bio_to_users.rb
20180412193721_acts_as_votable_migration.rb
20180416212245_create_notifications.rb
20180416235802_create_follow_join_table.rb
```

**20180416212245_create_notifications.rb**

```
CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1] 
  def change 
    create_table :notifications do |t| 
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true 
      t.references :notified_by, foreign_key: true 
      t.references :post, foreign_key: true 
      t.integer :identifier 
      t.string :notice_type 
      t.boolean :read 

      t.timestamps 
    end 
  end
end
```

I will wait for your suggestions Thank you.

Comment: Try running `heroku run rake db:migrate:status`. This will tell you which migration is causing the problem.

Comment: Would help if you posted the migration itself. As well as the names of the associations you're connecting in your models. Looks like it may be an inflection issue, though. `bies` vs `byes` (or `bys`).

Comment: can you please post the content of `20180416212245_create_notifications.rb`

Comment: @moveson I did and the last two rb files are "down" status whereas the rest of migration's status is "up".

Comment: @pdobb class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :notified_by, foreign_key: true
      t.references :post, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :identifier
      t.string :notice_type
      t.boolean :read

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not pointing the reference to the correct table. For an example the notified_by_id should be using the foreign key reference. In that sense the "notified_bies" doesn't exist. If "notified_by_id" is the value from the users table then add it as follows,

```
t.references :user
```

Comment: There is no notified related value in the users table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
 `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `user_id` integer,
 `notified_by_id` integer,
 `post_id` integer,
 `identifier` integer,
 `notice_type` varchar,
 `read` boolean,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES "users" ( "id" ),
 FOREIGN KEY(`notified_by_id`) REFERENCES "notified_bies" ( "id" ),
 FOREIGN KEY(`post_id`) REFERENCES "posts" ( "id" )
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `email` varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `encrypted_password` varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `reset_password_token` varchar,
 `reset_password_sent_at` datetime,
 `remember_created_at` datetime,
 `sign_in_count` integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `current_sign_in_at` datetime,
 `last_sign_in_at` datetime,
 `current_sign_in_ip` varchar,
 `last_sign_in_ip` varchar,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,

Comment: `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `user_name` varchar,
 `avatar_file_name` varchar,
 `avatar_content_type` varchar,
 `avatar_file_size` integer,
 `avatar_updated_at` datetime,
 `bio` text
);

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting occured while creating the foreign key

**Updated Answer**

This is the reason for the error

```
t.references :notified_by, foreign_key: true
```

Now, I don't believe that you have a model named `NotifiedBy` which you are trying to reference here.

Maybe you just need an index here on the field. So, you might need to change this to

```
t.integer :notified_by, index: true
```

**Old Answer**

```
FOREIGN KEY ("notified_by_id")
  REFERENCES "notified_bies" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_ff8a02c41d"
```

You must be creating a reference or a foreign key in `20180416212245_create_notifications.rb`.

Removing the entry should fix the issue

Comment: The below is my CreateNotification rb file. Can you explain more about? CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :notifications do |t|
          t.references :user, foreign_key: true
          t.references :notified_by, foreign_key: true
          t.references :post, foreign_key: true
          t.integer :identifier
          t.string :notice_type
          t.boolean :read

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end

Comment: It seems CreateNotification already has both references and foreign key. no?

Comment: and I got an error when generating migration like "rails g migration AddNotifiedByToNotifications notified_by:references". SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: notified_by_id: ALTER TABLE "notifications" ADD "notified_by_id" integer/mnt/studata05/AC/Aca15js/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'